# Understanding an Application based on the OS interaction with a Hypervisor

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, operating-systems, hypervisor

Following I will ask a few specific questions but I will set the stage first.
My goal is to monitor Applications in a very odd place - between the OS and a Hypervisor.
If you have comments about this probably unachievable goal please do educate me. One good advice or link can save me days of work.

Now to my current attempt. I installed on WinXP a VirtualBox (being open-source) and got a guest OS of latest Ubuntu running within.
Where should I go next? Can I set the logs to show all memory/CPU/disk instructions of the guest OS?

Thanks,
Dewy

Comment: There should be an option in VirtualBox to show log and show all actions of Guest OS. Can't recall where.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'real' notion of "between the OS and Hypervisor". The hypervisor itself is nothing but an optimized hardware emulation of a generic PC platform.

There's the option to configure the hypervisor to place limitations on the Guest operating system. Or, [You could monitor the Memory/CPU and general performance using perfmon](https://serverfault.com/questions/33776/get-a-history-of-cpu-memory-usage). Anything besides that would be the same as trying to monitor the performance of a kernel in userspace. Difficult, if not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux guest, I'd check out `strace`  http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace

It does a big chunk of what you want, though not all.

The closest Windows equivalent is probably `Process Monitor` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx